# How to change screen settings or display options from terminal (L)ubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

My laptop has had a mishap, a heavy impact on the keyboard :/

Something inside has been damaged and the screen is now very fuzzy and flickering. BUT, it looks perfect when connected to TV via HDMI. The only problem is the screen resolution is different so the taskbar/menu is not visible.

Is there a way to get into screen settings via the terminal? I can open the terminal via CTRL ALT T but using gnome-control-center opened up an empty panel with no config options.

As far as I can tell from the tv screen, the laptop itself is working perfectly, the display is the only problem. If we weren't in lockdown I'd have it to the repairman pronto but for now it's going to have to be a temporary solution.

Any advice gratefully received!

Comment: Try running `gnome-display-properties`. That was the name if I remember correctly.

Comment: Many laptops have a fn-display button that will toggle between mirroring, internal+external, internal only, external only etc and is the easiest fix in my opinion (if the resolution is different between internal & external monitors, the mirror can cause part of display to not appear on the lower-resolution display which this fixes..)

Comment: Thanks both. I've just had a play with the fn buttons but nothing is happening. gnome-display-properties gives the command not found error and something I read this morning suggests that gnome-control-center (gives me a blank panel) doesn't work unless i'm in the gnome environment which I'm not - I think - I'm using the LTE env.

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 LTS uses the LXDE interface by default, my system had `xrandr` already installed so it may provide an option (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution)

Comment: Oh, thank you - I will check this and let you know how I get on

Comment: I feel a little bit stupid now because I realise that I can click one of the folders which ARE visible on the tv screen and from that, selet applications and preferences to change my settings. So I now have a perfectly uable display on the tv screen.  Oddly, the laptop screen, while flickering badly, is also more visible and almost useable in itself, though probably not good for epliptics or migraine sufferers. I will stick with the tv screen for now and see how things go. Many many thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
lxqt-config-monitor
```

It should open monitor settings and you can change resolution from there